# What gas-stations, restaurants etc are in the certain city?

Tags: php, api

Are there any APIs where I can show the list of gas-stations, restaurants etc. in the certain city or even better by post number? Thank you.

Comment: It's not PHP, but Google provides a JS api for its local search: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/localsearch/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google offers an SQL API that can interact with their Fusion Tables.  You should be able to achieve what you are looking for with it.

http://code.google.com/apis/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's called a business directory. You'll need to purchase the file. Depending on your usage, the price will vary. Here's one [description](http://library.dialog.com/bluesheets/html/bl0531.html).

You could also scrape Google Local, Yahoo or other web sites. But any use other than personal will be against their tos (terms of service).

ps And probably any scraping, by definition, would also not be ok.

Comment: Factually wrong (the question asked for an API, not a file) and unnecessarily rude answer. There are free APIs, among others from Google, to do exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at :

http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/get_local_search_results_with_google_maps_and_ajax_apis/

It might be a starting point for what you need.

Answer (score 3):

There are several API services available that will help you find businesses for given location. These services are commonly known as directory, local, places or map search. One of the more complete list can be found at [Programmable Web](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=Mapping). For example, take a look at [Google Local](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/google-places%20Google%20Places), [TownMe Geo](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/townme-geo%20TownMe%20Geo%20API), [Yahoo Local Search](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/yahoo-local-search), [SimpleGeo](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/simplegeo-places) and [Bing Maps Search](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/bing-maps-search%20Bing%20Maps%20Search%20API). Be sure to read Term of Services because most of these services allow only certain number of requests per day and many don't allow commercial usage. For example, TownMe and SimpleGeo have relatively relaxed terms while Yahoo doesn't have commercial license but they are OK with non-commercial use for up to 5000 queries per day.

Answer (score 1):

There is a easy way to get this information using yahoo local search . You can get started easily using [YQL Console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console) .

A sample query for example:

```
select * from local.search where zip='94085' and query='pizza'
```

This would show pizza centers around California region . See output [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20%2a%20from%20local.search%20where%20zip=%2794085%27%20and%20query=%27pizza%27) .

To know what parameters you can use exactly

```
desc local.search
```